# Possible to Get Puppeteer Audio Feed and/or Input Audio Directly to Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I want to input WAV or MP3 into puppeteer as a microphone, however while in headless the application is muted, so I was wondering if there was a way to get input directly into the browser.

I am also wondering if it's possible to get a feed of audio from the browser while in headless, and/or record the audio and place it in a folder.

Comment: Sorry, it's not definitely clear from the question — but what is the task? Why use puppeteer if you just want to record audio from a microphone?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48264537/247696

Comment: Also see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52095416/how-can-i-correctly-provide-a-mock-webcam-video-to-chrome/52188760

Answer (score 14):

I ended up using this solution. First, I enabled some options for Chromium:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: [
    '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
  ],
  ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--mute-audio'],
});
```

Remember to close Chromium if it is open already.

I created an `<audio>` element with the `src` set to the file that I wanted to input. I also overrode `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`, so that it returns a `Promise` with the same stream as the audio file, rather than from the microphone.

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://example.com', {waitUntil: 'load'});
await page.evaluate(() => {
  var audio = document.createElement("audio");
  audio.setAttribute("src", "http://example.com/example.mp3");
  audio.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");
  audio.setAttribute("controls", "");
  audio.onplay = function() {
    var stream = audio.captureStream();
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = async function() {
       return stream;
    };
  });
  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(audio);
});
```

Now whenever the website's code calls `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`, it will get the audio stream from the file. (You need to make sure the audio is playing first.)

Answer (score 4):

User Flimm's [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58033727/247696) was on the ball. Not sure why it did not work for him. Adding the answer here for others, as I do not have sufficient reputation to comment on his answer.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true,
  args: [
    '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
    '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
    '--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\newtest.wav',
  ],
```

One possible reason might be that in Windows, the slashes need to be doubled as I've done here.

The --use-fake-device-for-media-stream also needs to be enabled for this to work.

The wav file should be 44.1 kHz, 16-bit. [This sample one](https://freewavesamples.com/ensoniq-zr-76-01-dope-77-bpm) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by inputting as a microphone, but you can enable audio in headless mode. This should work:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
   ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--mute-audio']
});
```

Comment: Also, you might be interested in this option: `puppeteer.launch({args: [ '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream' ]})`

Answer (score 1):

In theory, to load the file `example.wav` and use it as if it were microphone input, this should work:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: [
    '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
    '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream',
    '--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=/path/example.wav',
    '--allow-file-access',
  ],
  ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--mute-audio'],
});
```

I was told that you need to make sure that Chrome has been closed before running the script, and that the .wav file needs to be 41khz and 16-bit.

However, I could not get it to work :(