# How can I record audio while using Puppeteer?

Tags: typescript, browser, puppeteer, audio-recording, ecmascript-2020

### Background

I am making software that records the audio of streaming seminars. Although I automated to enter a seminar as a user, I haven't found a way to record its audio.

### What to do

I know there are a lot of tools to automate browsing tasks. Of them, I chose to use Puppeteer and know how to record while browsing by Puppeteer.

Suppose you are given a `page` of Puppeteer. You need to record the audio of its page. My script is written in TypeScript, so it is highly appreciated for you to write answers in TypeScript! Of course, JavaScript is, of course, welcome!

```js
import { Page } from 'puppeteer';

export const AudioRecord = async (page: Page): Promise<void> => {
  // record the audio of page
};
```

### What I did

I googled for a solution and found [something that seemed related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264537/auto-allow-webcam-access-using-puppeteer-for-node-js), but this script was not working in my environment (ES2020).